# css transition delay not working with background-color

Tags: css

I'm trying to delay an animation

Here is my css:

```
div {
    background-color: #000; 
    height: 100px;
    transition-delay: 5s;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

When I hover my mouse over the `div` the animation starts immediately, no delay. When I inspect the element I see that there is a css property `transition-delay` Any suggestion why this doesn't work ? (I'm using chrome)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Ne9/)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition-delay/ check this link here you dont need to use transition : then use transition-delay only i guess you didnt google that first eithe r:)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to declare your `transition-delay` after the `transition`.

```
div {
    background-color: #000; 
    height: 100px;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
    transition-delay: 5s;
}
```

Or declare it in a single statement:

```
transition: background-color 1s ease 5s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7Ne9/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Ne9/4/

```
transition-property:background-color;
transition-duration:1s;
transition-delay:2s;
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The way ure doing is for transition in the reverse way i.e when is unhover the div that is wen the transition occurs. Try the opposite way:

```
div {
    background-color: #000; 
    height: 100px;

}

div:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition-delay: 5s;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```